# Direct push notification to specific screen when app is terminated

Tags: flutter, push-notification, flutter-notification

I want the user to land to a specific screen when a notification is tapped from a terminated state. I know that the `getInitialMessage()` handles notifications from terminated state but it doesn't seem to navigate to the screen I want.

Here's the code:

```
AndroidNotificationChannel channel;
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
 final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: "Main Navigator");
 Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
   flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channel.description,
                icon: '@drawable/splash',
                playSound: true
              ),
            ));
            navigatorKey.currentState
                      .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OrdersScreen()));
}
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel', // id
      'High Importance Notifications', // title
      'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
      importance: Importance.high,
    );
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
            ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    
     
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  void initState() {
         var initializationSettingsAndroid  = AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/splash');
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android:initializationSettingsAndroid);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
     FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage message) {
          print('Inside get initial message'); 
      if (message != null) {
        print('Inside message not null'); 
          navigatorKey.currentState
                       .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OrdersScreen()));
      }
    });
}
}
```

As you can see, I want to navigate to ordersscreen but I instead land on the landing page. What am I missing? It works fine when the notification is tapped from background state or foreground state, but not from terminated state.

Comment: Do you get the notifications when the app is terminated? I'm trying this on my app with android studio, FCM, foreground and background is working, but when the state is terminated, it won't work nor show the notification.

Comment: And for the Navigation, inside the `flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);` you have a onSelecNotification method where you can specify on what route you want to send the user to.

Comment: are this issue solved yet

Comment: No it hasn't been resolved yet. Let me know if it works for you.